# python selenium checking for element in chrome doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, python-webbrowser

This works just fine in Firefox. When I use Chrome, once the page fully loads it doesn't print "element loaded", and it doesn't go to timeout either. It just waits forever.
I've tried using `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located` but it makes no difference. I've tried `all_elements` too. Any advice?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://url.com")
timeout = 10
email = ("email@gmail.com")

try:
    email_form_wait = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]')))
    print ("element loaded")
    email_form = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]')
    email_form.send_keys(email, Keys.ENTER)
    
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading took too much time!")
```

**Update**
For debugging reasons, I've been trying this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://url.com")

time.sleep(5)
print("end wait")
```

This works as expected on Chrome, but when I add

```
email_form = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]')
print("element found")
```

at the end of the code, it doesn't even print "end wait", it's stuck waiting forever and then it prints "end wait" and returns an error only after I force close the browser.

Comment: can you share url of the page please

Comment: I can't share it publicly unfortunately. I could share it in private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Site Isolation` is a security feature in Chrome that offers additional protection against some types of security bugs. It uses Chrome's sandbox to make it harder for untrustworthy websites to access or steal information from your accounts on other websites.

Try opening chrome driver with the following options supplied.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-site-isolation-trials")

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

s = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, chrome_options=options)

driver.get(url)
username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="username"]')
username.send_keys('email@gmail.com')
submit = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ca56ae105.c03eb9739.c026ac3bb.ca0d6234f._button-login-id')
submit.click()
password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="password"]')
password.send_keys('password')
continueButton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ca56ae105.c03eb9739.c026ac3bb.ca0d6234f._button-login-password')
continueButton.click()
```

Comment: service=s undefined name s